# Get wireless SSID through shell script on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, shell

Is there any way to get the SSID of the current wireless network through a shell script on Mac OS X?

Answer (score 150, accepted):

The command

```
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Resources/airport -I
```

will give you details about your current wireless network connection.

To get specifically the SSID, use this command:

```
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Resources/airport -I | awk -F: '/ SSID/{print $2}'
```

To retrieve SSID names that might have colons as well as spaces:

```
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Resources/airport -I  | awk -F' SSID: '  '/ SSID: / {print $2}'
```

Comment: When I do the second command, it doesn't work properly. The SSID I am connected to has spaces in it and that command only shows the first word.

Comment: @Mark: I've updated the second command to work for SSIDs with spaces in them as well. Hope this helps!

Comment: Tell `awk` to use `:` as a delimiter and you'll get your whole SSID: `awk -F':' '/ SSID/ {print $2}'`

Comment: @Johnsyweb: According to 802.11 standard, SSID may also contain the field separator ':'

Comment: If you have spaces at the start and at the end use this `awk -F' SSID: '  '/ SSID: / { print "x",$2,"x"}'`

Comment: This command supports SSIDs with embedded colons, spaces, etc: `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Resources/airport -I | sed -n '/SSID: /s/.*SSID: //p'`

Essentially: Suppress normal sed output, except for the line containing 'SSID: ', which is printed, but only after removing 'SSID: ' and all preceding characters.

Comment: Airport command line tool is deprecated now

Answer (score 52):

Where *isn't* there a wheel in need of re-inventing?

```
networksetup -getairportnetwork en1 | cut -c 25-
```

is what you'd use on 10.6, 10.7 changed the "Hardware Port" name from "Airport" to "Wi-Fi", and therefore you'd cut off one less letter,

```
aru$ networksetup -getairportnetwork en1 | cut -c 24-
Yorimichi
```

In case the device is named something other than `en1`, one needs to first get the correct device name, than the corresponding SSID:

```sh
networksetup -listallhardwareports | awk '/Wi-Fi/{getline; print $2}' | xargs networksetup -getairportnetwork
```

Comment: Note Johnsyweb's comment above re: awk; instead of using `cut` you could run `networksetup -getairportnetwork en1 | awk -F": " '{print $2}'`, which will work regardless of whether the label contains "Airport" or "Wi-Fi".

Comment: Downside here is that you have to know your wlan interface name.  I have seen e1 on macs that have a built-in ethernet (assigned e0) making the WiFi interface `e1` which seems to be the case in this answer.  Others have `e0`.  This is an easy edit of course but if you try to make it generic the answer by @Chetan seems easier

Comment: Or, use: networksetup -getairportnetwork en1 | cut -d':' -f2 | cut -c 2-

Comment: `networksetup -getairportnetwork en1 | cut -d ' ' -f 4` works fine, it doesn't depend on the OS version

Comment: Or even better with 
     "networksetup -getairportnetwork en1 | awk '{print $NF}' "
there is no need to count since it always gets the last field (while separated by spaces).

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as the accepted answer of using /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Resources/airport doesn't work when the script is run in non interactive mode.

Answer (score 7):

The following has been tested on OS X and prints the SSID without any hard-coded column widths:

```
system_profiler SPAirPortDataType | awk -F':' '/Current Network Information:/ {
    getline
    sub(/^ */, "")
    sub(/:$/, "")
    print
}'
```

Essentially, this takes the output of `system_profiler SPAirPortDataType`, and prints the line after "`Current Network Information:`" trimming leading whitespace and the trailing colon (since SSIDs can contain `:`s).

Comment: `system_profiler` has a small delay on my OS X 10.8. `networksetup` needs Airport interface name. I'd prefer `airport | sed -n 's/^ *SSID: //p'`

Comment: Thanks.  On macOS Sierra it's `airport --getinfo | sed -n 's/^ *SSID: //p'`

Comment: works well for apple network adapters, which isn't a PITA, unless you're using a USB nic on a macbook that has a busted network card.