# Why are results different when passing an argument to a function from piping to it as a process?

Tags: bash, function, shell, pipe

I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369758/how-to-trim-whitespace-from-a-bash-variable) with two solutions for trimming whitespace: piping to `xargs` and defining a `trim()` function:

```sh
trim() {
    local var="$*"
    # remove leading whitespace characters
    var="${var#"${var%%[![:space:]]*}"}"
    # remove trailing whitespace characters
    var="${var%"${var##*[![:space:]]}"}"   
    echo -n "$var"
}
```

I prefer the second because of one comment:

> This is overwhelmingly the ideal solution. Forking one or more external processes merely to trim whitespace from a single string is fundamentally insane – particularly when most shells (including bash) already provide native string munging facilities out-of-the-box.

I am getting, for example, [the wifi SSID on macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481005/get-wireless-ssid-through-shell-script-on-mac-os-x) by piping to `awk` (when I get comfortable with regular expressions in bash, I won't fork an `awk` process), which includes a leading space:

```
$ /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Resources/airport -I | awk -F: '/ SSID/{print $2}'
 <some-ssid>

$ /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Resources/airport -I | awk -F: '/ SSID/{print $2}' | xargs
<some-ssid>

$ /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Resources/airport -I | awk -F: '/ SSID/{print $2}' | trim

$ wifi=$(/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Resources/airport -I | awk -F: '/ SSID/{print $2}')

$ trim "$wifi"
<some-ssid>
```

Why does piping to the `trim` function fail and giving it an argument work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because your `trim()` function is expecting a positional argument list to process. The `$*` is the argument list passed to your function. For the case that you report as not working, you are connecting the read end of a pipe to the function inside which you need to fetch from the standard input file descriptor.

In such a case you need to read from standard input using `read` command and process the argument list, i.e. as

```sh
trim() {
    # convert the input received over pipe to a a single string 
    IFS= read -r var
    # remove leading whitespace characters
    var="${var#"${var%%[![:space:]]*}"}"
    # remove trailing whitespace characters
    var="${var%"${var##*[![:space:]]}"}"   
    echo -n "$var"
}
```

for which you can now do

```
$ echo "    abc    " | trim
abc
```

or using a command substitution syntax to run the command that fetches the string, that you want to pass to `trim()` with your older definition.

```sh
trim "$(/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Resources/airport -I | awk -F: '/ SSID/{print $2}')"
```

In this case, the shell expands the `$(..)` by running the command inside and replaces it with output of the commands run. So now the function sees `trim <args>` which it interprets as a positional argument and runs the string replacement functions directly on it.

Comment: Can even use Bash's built-in RegEx engine with: `[[ "$var" =~ ^[[:space:]]*(.*[^[:space:]]) ]]` and `printf '%s' "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"` to stream the result to `stdout`.

Comment: Agreed, but my answer is trying to explain the actual problem OP was facing and not conjure up an alternate way to solve their problem